# Mocking Python object instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, mocking, python-unittest

I want to mock an object's instantiation so that the returned object is a MagicMock object.  My files are structured like this:

```
home_folder
|
|-namespace
|  |-Class1.py
|  |-Class2.py
|
|-tests
   |-unit_tests
      |-test_Class2.py
```

The contents of Class1.py are:

```
class Class1:
    ... class members ...
```

The contents of Class2.py are:

```
from Class1 import Class1

class Class2(Class1):

    classMethod(self):
        objInst = Class1()

        ... some logic ...

        return objInst
```

The contents of test_class2.py are:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from Class1 import Class1
from Class2 import Class2
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class TestClass2(TestCase):

    @patch("namespace.Class2.Class1")
    def test_classMethod(self, mock_class1):
        cl2Obj = Class2()

        cl1Obj = MagicMock(Class1())

        mock_class1.return_value = cl1Obj

        r = cl2Obj.classMethod()

        self.assertEqual(cl1Obj, r)
```

Running this test gives me:

```
<Class1.Class1 object at 0xnum> != <MagicMock name='Class1()' spec='Class1' id=num>
```

I tried using

```
@patch("namespace.Class1.Class1")
```

but that didn't help.  Trying

```
mock_class1.__init__.return_value = cl1Obj
```

throws an error saying

```
Attribute Error: 'method' object has no attribute 'return_value'
```

How do I mock objInst = Class1() so that objInst ends up holding a MagicMock object?

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. `mock_class1` is already a callable object and will return another mock - the same one wherever it is called. So this works fine:

```
class TestClass2(TestCase):

    @patch("namespace.Class2.Class1")
    def test_classMethod(self, mock_class1):
        cl2Obj = Class2()
        cl1Obj = mock_class1()
        r = cl2Obj.classMethod()
        self.assertEqual(cl1Obj, r)
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work. cl2Obj.classMethod() is returning an instantiation of Class1, not a mock object at all.